# Gyro rate gets increase problem

Tags: sensors

I am using PID controller to stabilize quadcopter. Its working well on the jig. But when I removed jig it went up and hit ceiling. I analyzed my data and from which I come to the conclusion that at static poisition my gyro sensor is outputing +-6deg/sec but when I start motors (without being control in) gyro rate jupms to +-30deg/sec. This increase in rate due to vibrational noise is causing quadcopter to liftup without beign my intension. Any suggestions to get rid from this vibrational noise?

Comment: What axis is the gyro sensor measuring?

Comment: roll and pitch axis

Comment: What are you using to control desired/actual altitude?

Comment: I am using PID control

Comment: Sorry... I meant what sensor are you using to measure altitude so that you can control it.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a low pass filter to eliminate the vibrational noise.

You should also correct the drift in your gyro measurement using some form of altitude sensor.

Comment: when I used low passfilter, it actually attenuating actual signal and i am loosing control. Noise is remove but actually low pass filter delays the output to one previous step. I am correcting that drift using accelerometer.

Comment: Low pass filtering is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a kalman filter if you want to remove the noise without  disfiguring the usefull part of the gyroscope's signal.

Comment: Even though the actual algorithm of Kalman Filter is simple, meeting the requirements of the filter is not easy besides the model must be specified accurately.